# Vue JS - How to save the selected value of a radio button to local storage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, local-storage

I have two radio buttons that are connected to each other, they accept a boolean value, either true or false, I need to do so that when one of these values is selected, the value is stored in the local storage, for example, it chooses true, the true value is stored in the local storage if then chose false the true value was deleted and the false value was kept and vice versa I think the problem is clear

You can also look at my [code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-lehmann-tb4qi)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <label
        >One
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="true" v-model="websiteAccept" />
      </label>
      <label
        >No
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="radio"
          value="false"
          v-model="websiteAccept"
        />
      </label>
      <p>{{ websiteAccept }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      websiteAccept: null,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: where is your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a watcher to save the value of `websiteAccept` to local storage whenever the value changes.

For example:

```
  data() {
    return {
      websiteAccept: null,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    websiteAccept(value) {
      this.saveToLocalStorage(value);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    saveToLocalStorage(value) {
      localStorage.setItem("websiteAccept", value);
    },
  }
```

[Here's an updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/store-input-value-in-local-storage-qt6rl?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue):